# Registering an open-generic type in Autofac

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac, structuremap

For various reasons we are needing to use Autofac in on of our libraries. We are currently using Structuremap and are having trouble converting the following to Autofac

```
For(typeof(Data.New.IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Data.New.Repository<>));
```

We are trying the following in Autofac

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

And receiving the following error

> System.ArgumentException: 'The type 'Repository`1[T]' is not assignable to service 'IRepository`1'.'

Comment: There is special method for open generic `builder.RegisterGeneric(....` rest is the same

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius this solved my issue, if you add an answer will mark is as solved. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I added it as an answer then as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special method `RegisterGeneric` in Autofac for open generics:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```